# Populate from treeview to textboxes in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

i have a database (ms access) with two tables which are tbl_Reqs and tbllab i populated the treeview node with the tbl_Reqs now i want the use the select node of the treeview to populate data from the second table to the textboxes.

Thanks in advance house..

[image]

```vb
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'MolotobankiDataSet.tbllab' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.TbllabTableAdapter.Fill(Me.MolotobankiDataSet.tbllab)
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'MolotobankiDataSet.tbl_Reqs' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.Tbl_ReqsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.MolotobankiDataSet.tbl_Reqs)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Tbl_ReqsBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Me.Validate()
        Me.Tbl_ReqsBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.MolotobankiDataSet)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Tbl_ReqsTableAdapter.Connection.Open()
        TreeView1.Nodes.Clear()
        FillTree("1", "Library", Nothing)
        Tbl_ReqsTableAdapter.Connection.Close()

    End Sub

    Public Sub FillTree(ByVal Key As String, ByVal Txt As String, ByVal N As TreeNode)

        Dim cn As OleDbConnection
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand
        Dim NN As TreeNode
        If N Is Nothing Then
            NN = TreeView1.Nodes.Add(Key, Txt)
        Else
            NN = N.Nodes.Add(Key, Txt)
        End If
        cn = Tbl_ReqsTableAdapter.Connection
        cmd = New OleDbCommand("select * from tbl_Reqs where ID_Parent='" & Key & "'", cn)
        Dim dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
        Do While dr.Read()
            FillTree(dr("PK_Req"), dr("mem_Req"), NN)
        Loop
        dr.Close()
        cmd.Dispose()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Have you though about using the DataSet to create [Relations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataset.relations) between the two DataTables? A relation that you didn't specify in the question.

Comment: No, i will give it a try and thanks for the assistance...

Comment: have tried it but no way out for me... any more help thanks

Comment: Well, you have stored a PK there (`PK_Req`). I assume you have a Key in the other DataTable that relates to this one. So, bind your Controls (those on the right) to a BindingSource linked to the second DataTable. When you click on a Node, extract the PK and select the corresponding record(s?) in the second DataTable. The CurrencyManager does the rest.

Comment: You could do the same with DataSet Relations. You operate on the first DataTable instead of the second in this case, which can be useful if you have other Controls that support a DataSource there. The TreeView does not (unless you build one that does, as [someone else has already done](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9241/DataBound-TreeView-Control) -  I'm not suggesting to use that Custom Control, but most commercial products do the same).

Comment: Thanks in a million... it works, do appreciate

Comment: Well, you're welcome :) You could post your solution as the answer, it could help others.

Comment: ok i will, when done with it